# Item set and SLR(1) Questions in Compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, grammar, ll-grammar, lalr

I ran into a Old Exam question that solved by our TA. anyone could help me?

when we create `SLR(1)` about `S--> aSb | a` grammar, one of the item set `LR(0)` is like as:

> { S-->a.Sb, S-->a., S-->.aSb, S-->.a}

about extracted rule from above set, which of them is True:

```
a) one reduced and 2 shift and 1 goto is produced.

b) one reduced and 2 shift and2 goto is produced.

c) two reduced and 1 shift and 1 goto is produced.

d) when we input a, we have conflict.
```

anyone could say why (3) is correct? some detail about this question ?

EDIT: i think Goto refer to Action and goto tables.
[image]

Comment: Did you write correctly the SLR(0) item? There's a lonely a at the end... Also what you ask doesn't really make much sense...actions are only shift and reduce so it's not clear what do you mean by produces a goto.

Comment: @Bakuriu, sorry i edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible lookahead symbols: `a`, `b`, and `$` (the end-of-input marker). The transitions are:

```
 lookahead        action
 ---------        ------
     a            shift
     b            reduce S->a
     $            reduce S->a
```

And one goto action is produced, on the non-terminal S, with the target being the state `{S -> aS.b}`

Comment: would you please add a bit more detail? i'm sorry if i waste your time.

Comment: @Ali: if you compute the FOLLOW sets, what I wrote should be obvious by inspection of the state. Sorry to be short, but SO is not a substitute for reading a standard text on parsing theory. Anyway, think about what the action must be given the three possible following tokens.

Comment: Rici, can i compute here? http://hackingoff.com/compilers/predict-first-follow-set

Comment: Apparently so, but you might learn more doing it by hand and then checking. (The FOLLOW set is just the set of symbols which might follow a non-terminal in a valid sentence, so you can do it by eye. Just don't forget to augment the grammar with `S' -> S $` (you don't have to do that for most tools since the tool will do it automatically).

Comment: rici, i add my picture, would you please check it?

Comment: States 2 and 4 are the same, so the shift transition from state 2 should just loop back to itself. Other than that, it's fine. (Of course, it's missing the reduce action, but you knew that.)